# Restrict S3 Static Website access to Cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I understand this is a common question, but I was unsuccessful with their solutions.

I have two websites hosted on S3:

- bucket.ca (Allows `*.bucket.ca`)
- dev.bucket.ca (Allows `dev.bucket.ca`)

They are publicly accessible, but I do not want anyone to access their S3 url. So I edited the bucket policy with `StringEquals`.

One for each of the buckets:

`arn:aws:s3:::bucket.ca/*`
`arn:aws:s3:::dev.bucket.ca/*`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev.bucket.ca/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "random-hash"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the part that gets frustrating. Every time I make a change to Cloudfront or make a change to the bucket, the behavior is highly inconsistent.

`dev.bucket.ca` appears to be working as intended where its S3 url results in Access Denied, and I can access any of its child paths `dev.bucket.ca/*`. So I replicated this configuration for `bucket.ca`, but the result is always 403.

Checking back with `dev.bucket.ca`, I am no longer able to access it's child paths. `dev.bucket.ca/404` results in 403.

Is there a reliable way to test S3 and Cloudfront configurations? Each time Cloudfront is edited, the changes are slow to update. Should I be wiping my browser cache and reopen an incognito mode each time to get a more reliable result?

Comment: The normal method is to [Restrict Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

Comment: I explored this method. It doesn't work for Static Websites hosted on S3 according to the docs. I don't understand why either, so it would be nice to know.

Comment: @Dan I think this is because accesses through S3 endpoints are direct and under control of IAM while accesses through S3 Web HTTP Endpoints are public HTTP accesses like any other, preventing IAM from being able to determine whether they come from a given AWS service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To debug this issue, I reverted the policy to allow all public:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev.bucket.ca/*",
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy works fully for `bucket.ca` and `dev.bucket.ca`. So it looks like it's my conditional that is the issue.

`"aws:UserAgent": "random-hash"`

It turns out the custom header needed to be `User-Agent` and not `UserAgent`. So Cloudfront should use `User-Agent` for its custom header and S3 policy to use `UserAgent`.

I tested this after Cloudfront has been deployed, and both websites worked correctly. S3 buckets cannot be accessed either, which is great.

---

The working policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev.bucket.ca/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "RandomHash"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With the following cloudfront setting:

`Header Name: User-Agent`

`Value: MatchingRandomHash`

Comment: What was your full (redacted) policy that got this working?

Comment: @JohnathanElmore Updated above to what I am currently using for S3 and Cloudfront.

Comment: Did you block public access to the bucket ? ( Using the Block public access Checkbox )